# Task Pane app: how can I search/replace strings in Word document?

Tags: ms-office, office365

I'm developing a Task Pane app for MS Word. The requirement is to replace words surrounding with # in a Word document by words from data source.

For example, the Word document looks like:

```
Hello #UserName#, the total invoice of #ThisYear# should be #TotalInvoice#.
```

After clicking a button in the task pane app, the content of the document should look like:

```
Hello Jack, the total invoice of 2015 should be 300,000,000.00.
```

What should I do? Which API should I use?

I'm very new to office development. The thing I can do now is to create a very simple Task Pane app according to the demo.